# How to do Cassandra query logging in Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra

I'm trying to log all Cassandra queries of a Spring Boot application into a console. I'm using 3.11 version of Cassandra. Tried using Query Logger as shown in the code below, but I'm facing an error while autowiring Cluster:

> could not autowire. No beans of type 'Cluster' found.

Are there any alternative ways of logging the Cassandra queries from the application side ?

**CassandraConfig class:**

```
@Autowired
Cluster cluster;

//getters & setters of cluster
@Bean
public QueryLogger queryLogger(Cluster cluster) {
    QueryLogger queryLogger = QueryLogger.builder()
            .build();
    cluster.register(queryLogger);
    return queryLogger;
}
```

**application.yml:**

```
logging.level.com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL: DEBUG
```